# Why were my comment flags declined?

Tags: discussion

So this morning, I flagged these three comments to [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6737/1599) as 'no longer needed' because they were chatty or an answer in a comment:

[image]

The flags were declined. Why? **Can somebody tell me what improvement is suggested or what clarification is asked for?**

Comment: Since the flags were declined by a moderator, would you consider specifying that you expect answers from moderators (I mean, not the general users who can only give speculative answers as to why the flags were declined) @Tinkeringbell?

Comment: @EnglishStudent *"Can somebody tell me what improvement is suggested or what clarification is asked for?"* is something anyone can answer if its there, not just a mod ;-)

Comment: I'm seeing it more as an 'Why was my question closed/answer deleted" type of question where everybody can chime in.

Comment: I was influenced by the title of your question; "why were my comment flags declined?" It would be speculative for a general user to answer and primarily opinion based; only a mod can tell you *why* the comment flags were actually declined @Tinkeringbell. However any user can give you some ideas *what improvement is suggested or what clarification is asked for in those comments.*

Comment: @EnglishStudent That's okay... Next time, just think of it as a 'Why was my question closed?" --> There, everybody chimes in, not just the close-voters ;-)

Comment: So I have chimed in with my own answer @Tinkeringbell!

Comment: Yeah, very strange indeed. I have got a few declined here and there which on a second-time with a custom flag, perhaps another mod marked helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't decline these flags but I did delete these comments.

As you say, none of them are requesting improvement of the post and at least one if not more of them fail to meet our "be nice" policy.

> Eds -- I can call ya Eds, right? -- do be prepared for a fair amount of blowback in the answers. People really do like to be called by their names, and it seems kind of ... unproductive to insist on using a pronunciation you know she doesn't like.

The first part of this reads like the person who posted it is trying to make a point - *Do you like it when people intentionally say your name wrong?* That's not a very welcoming thing to do. Yes, the question seems to be a bit misguided but addressing that is what answers are for. Making snide remarks to prove a point isn't nice. Part of a good answer to this question will explain exactly what this comment says - and several of them do. It is no longer needed and has been deleted.

> *However, her pronunciation is just plain wrong to me, and I can't be untrue to myself by pronouncing it her way.* What an arrogant thing to think.

This is purely commentary on the question. It's unnecessary. It's also rude - we've now just called the OP "arrogant". Something being your interpretation of the truth **DOES NOT MAKE IT "NICE"**. We have a very strict "[be nice](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)" policy here. Calling people "arrogant" *is not nice*!

> "You can't memorize every little detail about everybody you work with." True. Concentrate on the important details, the most important of which is their name.

Like the first comment, this is already covered in half of the answers. It is not necessary.

I'm sorry your flags were declined. I would hate to dissuade regular flaggers from doing so based on confusing, mixed signals. Please, feel free to bring future flagging concerns to meta until we get these concerns ironed out.

Comment: So, I was correct in flagging them as 'no longer needed'? I shouldn't have flagged them as 'in need of moderator intervention' at the first try?

Comment: "No longer needed" was fine for all three of them. The second one could easily have been flagged with "rude/abusive". None of them should have required a custom flag.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer only attempts to explain why the flags were initially declined, because it was written *before* the comprehensive and definitive answer posted by moderator @Catija which explains why the comments were finally deleted.

---

I think those 3 comments were retained because they give useful feedback to OP that

1. it is rude and arrogant to insist on a pronunciation of a name different from what is preferred by the person
2. a person's name is an important detail
3. the related faulty assumptions in the question will lead to community disagreement and disapproval.

So they are not necessarily chatty nor answers-in-a-comment but clearly informing OP of defects in the reasoning with a view to reconsidering these assumptions to make it a better question and avoid downvotes and criticism in answers and comments.

Note: @Catija has clarified here that the use of the word 'arrogant' makes the second comment a rude comment.

---

Update: those comments are gone now, and OP explained that she had custom-flagged them again for moderator's attention. The deletion was confirmed by @Catija and I appreciate her prompt and effective action in this matter.

Comment: 2 is blatantly rude. it says clearly *What an arrogant thing to think.*

Comment: Well, @Tinkeringbell said that the comment flags were ***declined*** @ Catija?

Comment: I didn't decline them.

Comment: The problem has certainly  been solved now because all 3 comments have been deleted @Catija.

Comment: Yes. Because I deleted them.

Comment: If that was done in response to this meta question (or even otherwise) I appreciate it @Catija!

Comment: @EnglishStudent I flagged them a second time, for moderator attention, with a custom message explaining they were answers in comments/rude/not requests for clarification/suggesting improvements. I somehow feel I should just be able to flag these things as 'no longer needed', not as 'in need of moderator intervention'.

Comment: If what you're saying here is true, I'm indeed looking forward to see if the moderator that declined them can confirm that ;-)

Comment: That is why I said that the best and definitive answers to this particular question can only come from moderators @Tinkeringbell.

Comment: But they don't **have** to. Part of building a great community is that we can give each other input on whether something should have been flagged or not or removed or not without requiring the person who actually responded to the flags to do so. Many, many questions on MSE look like the sort of thing that only a CM or other staff could answer but it turns out that the devoted users there can often make an educated guess that is correct. Mods shouldn't *have* to respond to all of these themselves. If someone else can explain it, great.

Comment: They don't *have* to, for sure. In fact moderators cannot be forced to answer such a question @Catija. *No moderator decision really needs to be explained to the community.* However I was therefore compelled to be speculative in my own answer, which is why I appreciate your clear and forthright answer why you chose to delete those comments.

Comment: You have that backwards. Moderator decisions *should* be explained when we're asked for them... We have a lot of power and can do a lot of things but we are accountable to you and we need to be able to explain our choices.

Comment: *"Moderator decisions should be explained when we're asked for them... We have a lot of power and can do a lot of things but we are accountable to you and we need to be able to explain our choices."* __ I am glad you feel that way @Catija. That is a very responsible and healthy attitude for moderators to take, and it builds greater trust among the general members. Not every site on SE has moderators willing to explain their decisions to the community. So we are very lucky here at IPS!